# How to use FactoQGIS for Typological Analysis Principal Components Analysis (PCA) for vector features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, pca

How to use FactoQGIS for Typological Analysis Principal Components Analysis (PCA) for vector features in QGIS?

I have a shapefile of polygons as in the following image:

[image]

Both visually and as illustrated by the Rose Diagram (in the image below) using Line Histogram Tool QGIS plugin available from the following link: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LineDirectionHistogram/, it can be deduced that the overall orientation of the polygons is around 30 degrees, confirmed by calculating the mean of angle of orientation of all polygons.

[image]

I am looking for a Mathematical Tool to validate the mean angle.  I was advised to use the Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to find first eigenvector which gives the direction of the first principal direction.

I found FactoQGIS: a GUI tool based on an R script to perform Geometric Data Analysis in QGIS available from the following link: https://github.com/ESO-Rennes/FactoQGIS.

Below is the screenshot of FactoGIS Tool.

[image]

I have been trying the FactoQGIS Tool with different parameters, but could not generate results.
Which parameters should I set?

The shapefile of the polygons is available from the following link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BKp5VbR1aMAzCObGprvqeL0WSMqpTX32?usp=sharing

Comment: it seems like FactorQGIS is one of the developing field in GIS so please someone add the tag **FactoQGIS** to tag list

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of the FactoQGIS tool. FactoQGIS is not suited to address your issue. I recommend you instead to use the SDE plugin: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SDEllipse/